# Is it dangerous to leave phone on the charging stand for a long time?

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I have a wireless charger in the form of a phone stand.

[image]

I use it in two cases - directly for charging (of course) and as a stand, so that it is convenient to look at the phone while sitting at the table. My question is if it is dangerous to leave the phone on the charging stand when it is already charged. Because it charges quickly enough, and then just stays on it all day.

P.S. For info - I use iPhone 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not dangerous. The iPhone and charger handles charging automatically - there's no danger of "over-charging" or anything like that.